# what kind of an /l/ sound is this?

Tags: phonetics, laterals

[here](https://voca.ro/1fZQN5NhG00L).

some speakers of my native language use this /l/ sound instead of more common [ɫ~l] colloquially it is referred to as "soft l" and is transcribed as "ლь" which is a combination of the Georgian letter "ლ" and the Cyrillic soft sign.

though usage of this sound instead of [ɫ~l] is stigmatized and seen as a speech defect.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One would need a more extensive corpus to know what this is, but it seems to be [l] in the wrong context – it should be allophonically velarized. This is a mildly famous distribution exploited in Kenstowicz & Kisseberth's phonology textbook and theoretically exploited in Hale & Reiss *The phonological enterprise*. The crucial question is where this version of *l* appears, for example "always before [i,e], optionally before [a]". More tokens are required, since the vowel also has some peculiar phonatory properties which need to be controlled.

Comment: by peculiar phonatory properties  do you mean that it's more fronted?

Comment: Phonatory refers to laryngeal properties: harsh whispery voice.